# What is a skew-symmetric matrix?

Tags: matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

What is a skew-symmetric matrix?

It came under types of matrices in my text. I have learned square matrices.

Comment: here is an example of a $2\times 2$ skew symmetric matrix $\pmatrix{0&a\\-a&0}$

Comment: @abel And for 3x3?

Comment: $\pmatrix{0&-c&b\\c&0&-a\\-b&a&0}$ is an example of a $3 \times 3$ skew symmetric matrix.

Comment: you are welcome.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a square matrix $A$ satisfying $A^T=-A$---that is, its transpose is the negative of the original. If $B=A^T$, then $B_{ij}=-A_{ji}$.

A similar property for complex matrices is *skew-Hermitian*: $A^H=-A$. If $B=A^H$, then $B_{ij}=-\overline{A_{ji}}=-\Re(A_{ji})+\jmath\Im(A_{ji})$.

Note that these properties require the diagonal elements to be zero.

Comment: What is A^H ? Is it same as A^T

Comment: If $A$ is real, it is the same. If it is complex, it denotes the conjugate transpose.

Comment: Thank you for the 1st two lines. I understood skew-symmetric matix but I don't know what Hermitian means or those symbols in the2nd last line.

Comment: Ah, OK! Well, they concern matrices of complex numbers. If you haven't covered complex numbers yet then that part will indeed be confusing. We can leave it there for the benefit of other readers; and when you do cover complex numbers, you will have a head start...

Comment: Yes. There is a complex numbers chapter.

Comment: Sorry for the late upvote. Didn't have the required points till now.

Comment: Quite OK, thank you! Seems a shame you can't vote up the answers to your own questions.

Comment: I am sorry. But they don't allow until I reach 15. I actually can now and I did.